# File processing from a local drive for contiki-os

Tags: contiki

Please have a look at the following code. I am writing an application to process a file from a local host among different other processes for sky mote. Contiki cfs_open cannot open a file from a local drive. The goal is to open a file from a local drive and store in the flash (sky) for live streaming; streaming part is working. Any suggestions for file uploading using CFS.

```
 PROCESS(coffee_file_process, "Coffee file process");
 AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&coffee_file_process);
 PROCESS_THREAD(coffee_file_process, ev, data)
 {
      PROCESS_BEGIN();    

      char buf[100];
      int fd;
      fd=cfs_open("cate.txt", CFS_READ);
      if(fd >= 0) {
          cfs_write(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
          cfs_seek(fd, 0, CFS_SEEK_SET);  //compute the offset from the beginning of the  file. 
          cfs_read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
          printf("Read message: %s\n", buf);
          cfs_close(fd);
      }

      PROCESS_END();
 }
```

Comment: cate.txt file needs to be created at CFS file system. One way to do it by using sky-shell and reading the file using cfs_read().

Answer (score 1):

If you are simulating using Cooja you can [script it](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/wiki/Using-Cooja-Test-Scripts-to-Automate-Simulations#writing-to-flash-sky-c). On the real node there is no way past the serial. Either use the shell as suggested by Sarwarul or write your own serial to cfs dumper.